# Object or objectification?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to understand the concept "object" in JavaScript. It seems to me that there is no such thing as object, but only "objectification," strictly speaking. Following is the W3C's explanation about the mutability of JavaScript object:

"Objects are mutable...If y is an object, the following statement will not make a copy of y...var x = y; The object x is not a copy of y. It is y. Both x and y points to the same object. Any changes to y will also change x, because x and y are the same object." http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp

What is confusing to me is this: Are x and y objects, or do they point to the same object? Of does the explanation mean that x and y can be said to be the same object in that they point to the same object? I wonder if this is the definition of JavaScript object, and I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects can help. Nice articles explaining objects in javascript

Comment: What you're asking is how passing works, and if it's pass by reference or value. It's always pass by value, but for objects the value of the variable is a reference, so both `x` and `y` would be a reference to the same object, changing one would also change the other.

Comment: FYI: W3C and w3schools are not the same organization.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the explanations. The article is very helpful, and I didn't know that W3C and W3C School are not the same organization. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `x` and `y` are technically references to the same object in the memory.

When you create an object, and then assign that object to a different variable, all you're doing is copying the reference.

This example should give you a bit of an idea what's going on:

```js
var a = {
    prop: 123
};

var b = a;

a.foo = "bar";

alert("b.prop: " + b.prop);
alert("b.foo: " + b.foo);

delete a.prop;

alert("b.prop after `delete a.prop`: " + b.prop);
```

That said, variables like these are called "objects" for simplicity's sake.
It wouldn't make much sense to *"Add a new property to the object reference `a`"*.

Answer (score 0):

> What is confusing to me is this: Are x and y objects, or do they point
>   to the same object?

`x` and `y` are variables that each hold a reference to the same object.  If you are familiar with a language like C, then you can think of object references like pointers.  `x` and `y` each hold a pointer to the same object so you can modify that object via the pointer in `x` or `y` or you can assign the same reference to another variable `z`.

The object itself is separate from the variable and for objects I think its best to think of them separately.  One or more variables can point to the object.  In fact, the object will be garbage collected when there are no longer any live variables that contain a reference to the object (the object becomes unreachable).

Comment: Thanks much for the clear explanation. Now I see the picture. They are "separate." The "object reference" is the term that I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Are x and y objects?

Depends on whom you ask. This terminology always depends on the context in which it is used. Technically, `x` and `y` are variables (or, to be even more precise, names of variables or "identifiers" for them).
An object is always anonymous - it has no name. Objects do only have an [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(object-oriented_programming)), and a dynamic set of properties (key-value pairs) bound to them.

But when we want to refer to a specific object, we usually name it. And instead of saying "*the object referenced by the variable `x`*", we just call it "*the object `x`*".

In your specific example, both variables refer to the same object, and we say that `x == y`.

Comment: That's very interesting. I will keep this in mind and try to understand the "context." Thank you.